# How to interpret the following graph (hierarchical partitioning analysis)

Tags: multiple-regression

So I am reading an article about the estimation of species distributions, and cannot understand how to interpret the following graph (I am only referring to the bar graph on the left):

[image]

The different colored bars represent the different predictor variables used to explain the variance in species richness (cumulative/minimum/variation DHI). This is the result of using hierarchical partinioning analyses of the multiple regression models to show the relative contributions of each variable. In the article, it was stated that

- "Multiple linear models of all three DHIs explained 67%, 61%, and 65% of the variability in species richness of amphibians, mammals, and resident birds respectively."

Which means that the height of the bars represent the total variance explained of the multiple regression model. However, in the article it also said that:

- "cumulative DHI (green) being the most important in each of the regression models, minimum DHI (blue) the second most important, and variation DHI (red) the least important.

I don't understand this since the green bar for mammals and resident birds is much smaller than the red bars (variation DHI).
It also said:

- "Among the major taxa, the regression model for resident birds explained most variation in species richness"

I also don't understand why this is the case, since the overall height of the bar for resident birds is lower than that of amphibians.
Am I missing something here? How do I interpret this graph?